# How to use old server repository path for GIthub action CICD (self hosted)

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a production server where I already have a my project repository. Now I have setup github action for CICD. I have given my workspace path, but it is creating 2 subdirectory with same name as my repo name. Github action is not using my old repository , it is cloning the repository again. So in the server file structure I have 2 same project. Now I want to use single repository in my server directory.
My yaml code look like this -

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
 push:
  branches: [ deploy ]
 pull_request:
  branches: [ deploy ]


jobs:
 build:

  runs-on: self-hosted
  strategy:
   matrix:
    node-version: [14.x]

    # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

 steps:
 - uses: actions/checkout@v2
 - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
   uses: actions/setup-node@v2
   with:
     node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
     cache: 'npm'
 - run: npm i
 - run: npm run build:uat
   env:
     CI: false
 - run: rm -r /root/apps/frontend/build
 - run: mv /root/apps/frontend/frontend/build /root/apps/frontend/
```